# How to use @property properly

Tags: python, properties

How to rewrite the following example in order to properly use @property?

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, config_folder="", config_file="config.json"):
        self.set_config(config_folder, config_file)

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.config) as f:
            return json.load(f)

    def set_config(self, config_folder, config_file):
        self.BASE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
        self.config = self.BASE_DIR / config_folder / config_file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you can't pass multiple values using a property, so your `set_config` can't be a property as currently constructed.

Also, it's worth pointing out that your `get_config` and `set_config` don't really match, logically - `get_config` gives you the *contents* of a file, while `set_config`, instead of setting the contents, just sets the path name.  This type of asymmetry can lead to confusing bugs.

If you wanted to make this a property you might want to do it as two different things - one that gets/sets the path for on-disk storage, if that is important to manipulate, and one that gets/sets the actual data contents of the currently configured path.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the definitions of the path of the config file into the constructor:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, config_folder="", config_file="config.json"):
        self.base_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
        self.config_path = self.base_dir / config_folder / config_file

    @property
    def config(self):
        with open(self.config_path) as f:
            return json.load(f)
```

If you want to overwrite the config path afterwards, you can do just that by changing the attribute directly (note that it is the `config_path` attribute, not the `config` attribute):

```
conf = Config()
conf.config_path = "./other_config.json"
print(conf.config)
```

Alternatively you could keep a method like your `set_config` (probably better called `set_config_path`) around to deal with the `base_dir`.